# win10toast library (python) image : some trouble with the icon (0, 'LoadImage', 'No error message is available')

Tags: python

well its exactly as it sounds, the image of the notification does not show up

things ive tried:

1. converting the image to a png
2. converting the image to a jpeg
3. converting the image to an ico

so far those are all the solutions ive seen and none of them worked for me

here's my code:

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
import time

# One-time initialization
toaster = ToastNotifier()

path = "logo.ico"

# Show notification whenever needed
toaster.show_toast("python", "heres a neat test", threaded=True,
                   icon_path=path, duration=10)


while toaster.notification_active():
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: You should try using absolute path. There are some variables involved when relative path is used.

Comment: thanks ill try that out :)

Comment: nope didnt work, the same error pops up.